# Hitting Button cause crashing app

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have created a simple android app that take two number and display them by adding. It work properly when I enter values but if I don't enter values and hit the button the app crashes..guide me please and thanks in advance
Here is its XML Code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter first number"
    android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et_first"
    android:hint="Enter second number"
    android:inputType="number" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="addition"
    android:text="+" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_result"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_add"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Here is its MainActivity.Java code

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void addition(View view) {
    EditText first_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_first);
    float first = Float.parseFloat(first_number.getText().toString());
    EditText second_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_second);
    float second = Float.parseFloat(second_number.getText().toString());
    TextView tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    float result = first + second;
    tv_result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
 }
```

Comment: You answered the question by yourself. If you dont enter values its crash. Why? Because you work with the values inside your addition function. If there were empty the app crash surely. Just check inside your function if your input is there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that the `EditText` actually has text in it first or else you will get a `NumberFormatException` when you try and parse an empty String into a float.

```
String firstNumber = first_number.getText().toString();
float first = TextUtils.isEmpty(firstNumber) ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(firstNumber);
```

If you also want to handle invalid inputs as mentioned by a comment try the following method:

```
private float parseFloat(String floatStr) {
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(floatStr)) return 0;

    try {
         return Float.parseFloat(floatStr);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You can replace 0 with any other default you would like to use.
You could then do the following:
`float first = parseFloat(first_number.getText().toString());`

Comment: What if the `firstNumber` String is something like `"sdlkfsdf"`?

Comment: @RamV13 That is going to be hard when OP has `android:inputType="number"` in the layout file. Anyways if you want to handle invalid inputs you obviously need to use try/catch

Comment: Haha I didn't see that field in the XML. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like this:

```
       float first = 0.0, second = 0.0;
        EditText first_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_first);
        if(first_number.getText() != null && first_number.getText().length() > 0){ 
          first = Float.parseFloat(first_number.getText().toString());
        }
        if(second_number.getText() != null && second_number.getText().length() > 0){ 
          first = Float.parseFloat(first_number.getText().toString());
        }
        EditText second_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_second);
        float second = Float.parseFloat(second_number.getText().toString());
        TextView tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        float result = first + second;
        tv_result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, when you are not entering any number and still pressing the add button it will crash coz it will perform addition on 'NULL' and app will crash.

```
public void addition(View view) {

    EditText first_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_first);

    if(!first_number.equals("") && first_number!=null)
     float first = Float.parseFloat(first_number.getText().toString());

    EditText second_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_second);
    if(!second_number .equals("") && second_number !=null)
     float second = Float.parseFloat(second_number.getText().toString());

    TextView tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    float result = first + second;
    tv_result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```

In this way you will be checking for the null or empty EditText and hence your App won't crash, if you want more user friendly add **Else** block and throw some message via *Toast* :)

Happy Coding....

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
EditText first_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_first);
EditText second_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_second);

String first = first_number.getText().toString();
String second = second_number.getText().toString();

if(!first.isEmpty() && !second.isEmpty()){
    float firstNumber = Float.parseFloat(first);
    float secondNumber = Float.parseFloat(second);
    TextView tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    float result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    tv_result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```